# Initiate multisite with blog_id outside of wordpress

Tags: multisite

Is there a way to initiate multisite outside of wordpress with `blog_id` supplied? I can use `switch_to_blog` after initialization  but that way i can not get plugins activated for that site.
I am trying to make an email piping script. I know `blog_id` before initialization. So is there any way to pass `blog_id` and initiate that blog?